# Blank PDF when save from okHttp

Tags: android, pdf, okhttp

I have to save pdf file using bytes from http response.

If file is small (about hundreds of bytes, less than 1k) everything is ok, but if file is too large I saw (using another app via Intent) all pages white (number of pages is correct).

I save the document in external storage and pass uri to intent.

This is my code to get file from server and save it to external storage:

```
public static Observable<Integer> getDocument(final String id, final String service, final String filename){
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
            OkHttpClient client = HypeHttpClientBuilder.getOkHttpClient(200); //timeout
            RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                    .add("platform", HypeApplication.getDeviceType())
                    .add("function", service)
                    .add("pdfid",id)
                    .build();

            Request requests = HttpRequestBuilder.getRequest(formBody);
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(requests).execute();

                inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Hype");
                if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Directory not created");
                }
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, filename));
                int totalCount = inputStream.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
                int len;
                int readLen = 0;
                while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {

                    //System.out.println("download loop " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    readLen += len;

                }


                subscriber.onNext(readLen);


            }catch (Exception e){
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }finally {
                try {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                    if (outputStream != null) {
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            subscriber.onCompleted();


        }
    });
}
```

and this is code to start another activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",f)
                    , "application/pdf");

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            startActivity(intent);
```

**UPDATE**
I tried to use a proxy to intercept http call. 
So, I got file from proxy and file generated by my code and I compared them: there are some differences.

I got a simple solution using `UrlConnection` class.

```
URL url = new URL(URLSetting.getOldUrl());
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestProperty("appversion","2.0.0");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("platform", HypeApplication.getDeviceType())
                        .appendQueryParameter("function", service)
                        .appendQueryParameter("deviceid",HypeApplication.getDeviceId())
                        .appendQueryParameter("pdfid", id);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(builder.build().getEncodedQuery());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                conn.connect();


                inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
```

So, do you know if okHttp set as default encoding UTF-8?

Comment: I recommend `getFD().sync()` between `flush()` and `close()` on your `FileOutputStream`. Beyond that, download the PDF from the device and see if it is OK.

Comment: No. I put `getFD.sync()` like you said me, but I continue to see white pages of the document.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly is causing your problem, but you could try simplifying your code by using Okio API.

```
BufferedSource source = response.body().source();

Sink out = Okio.sink(outputFile);
try {
  while (!source.exhausted()) {
    Buffer buffer = source.buffer();
    out.write(buffer, buffer.size());
  }
} finally {
  out.close();
}
```

See if that changes anything.